# JavaScript Validation error message is not disappearing after I click submit

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

The code below validates a form with two fields. When I click the submit button without any data the error messages would show which is working fine but if I input data after and click submit button the error message doesn't disappear.

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var valid = true;
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["activityName"].value;
    if (x == "" || x == null) {
        document.getElementById("activityName").innerHTML = "Please Enter Activity Name";
        valid= false;
    }

    var r = document.forms["myForm"]["reporter"].value;
    if (r == "") {
        document.getElementById("reporter").innerHTML = "Please Enter Reporter";
    valid = false;
    }

    return valid;

}   
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" method="post" name="myForm" onsubmit=" return validateForm()">
    <div>
       <label for="myActivityName">*Activity Name:</label>
       <input type="text"  name="activityName" value="" placeholder="Enter Activity Name"  />
       <p id="activityName"></p>
    </div><br>

    <div>
       <label for="reporter">*Reporter:</label>
       <input type="text"  name="reporter" value="" placeholder="Enter Reporter "  />
       <p id="reporter"></p>
    </div><br>      
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you never "unvalidate" the form a.k.a. remove the previous validation errors. Before you return from validation, if there were no errors, just revert your validation checks. This will ensure it will "clean" your interface if nothing is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is right, but here is some code to back it up with.  Notice that the `innerHTML` of both `activityName` and `reporter` get (re)set back to empty before the validation occurs:

```
function validateForm() {
    var valid = true;
    document.getElementById("activityName").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("reporter").innerHTML = "";

    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["activityName"].value;
    if (x == "" || x == null) {
        document.getElementById("activityName").innerHTML = "Please Enter Activity Name";
        valid= false;
    }

    var r = document.forms["myForm"]["reporter"].value;
    if (r == "") {
        document.getElementById("reporter").innerHTML = "Please Enter Reporter";
        valid = false;
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir but can I ask you one more thing do you know where I have to put the confirm dialog so after it checks  the validation and I click the submit button it would ask if to accept the data or cancel it to make changes?

Comment: The explanation is too long for a comment but have a look here: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/confirm.htm